# Why UDP does not have flags?

Tags: tcp, udp

There is always a three way handshake in TCP session and have flags but why there is no flag in UDP session?

Comment: Why do you need flags? What problem are you trying to solve? This question is vague and too general. Please describe your actual problem and the steps you have taken to solve it.

Comment: i am using wireshark and researching on every packets which is being transferred between source and destination. I didn't get flags on UDP communication so i asked.

Answer (score 2):

The specification doesn't define flags because it is a simpler specification than TCP and more specifically it is stateless and uni-directional. There is no need for flags to track state or provide advanced modes because UDP doesn't have them.

The [specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc768.txt) describes the format.

It even states:

> This protocol  provides  a procedure  for application  programs  to send
>   messages  to other programs  with a minimum  of protocol mechanism

So it is minimalist by design.

Comment: I mean in the sense that a packet can be sent with no expectation of a reply. What the Wikipedia article means when it says "Works well in unidirectional communication"

Comment: 'Unidirectional' means that data can only go in one direction. 'Works well in' is not the same as 'is'.

Answer (score 0):

> why there is no flag in UDP session?

Because there is no such thing as a 'UDP session'. It is a connectionless protocol.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a Connection-oriented reliable transport protocol. Reliable in the sense it ensures the data to be delivered to the receiver. The reliability can be achieved some of the techniques congestion control, congestion avoidance, retransmitting etc, for those some details need about the current transmission state, data, packet length etc ..Flags or used many other different purposes . 
Refer the link :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

**Because UDP is a connectionless protocol and it UDP enables process-to-process communications.**
It allows packets to be dropped and received in a different order than they were transmitted, making it suitable for real-time applications where latency might be a concern.